# Why are some functions located densely and others are aligned and padded with int 3 instructions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, linker, disassembly

I compile the following program with Visual C++ 10:

```
include <Windows.h>
int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    Sleep( 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

and look into disassembly. There're lots of C++ runtime functions in the program image. Some functions are located densely - `ret` of some function is followed by the first instruction of the next function. For example,

```
` __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(ULONGLONG StackCookie)`
```

ends at address `004013B7` (there's a `ret` instruction) and address `004013B8` contains some other function for which the debugger can't find the source. Meanwhile

```
BOOL __cdecl _ValidateImageBase(PBYTE pImageBase)
```

ends at address `00401554` but the next function

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER __cdecl _FindPESection( PBYTE pImageBase, DWORD_PTR rva )
```

starts at address `00401560` and there're multiple `int 3` instructions between the latter two addresses.

Why the difference? Why some functions are put densely and others are separated with unreachable code?

Comment: Given your two examples: both functions begin at a multiple of `8`, and the one that ends at `7` just happens not to need any padding. If you can find another example that contradicts the hypothesis that functions are 8-aligned, please add it.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Okay, but there 11 bytes of padding, not 3.

Comment: Oops, no, I'm stupid. It's `54` in the second case, not `58`.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this behavior. You can notice as well that these functions start with a mov edi,edi intruction.

The int 3 instructions, along with the mov edi,edi instruction at the beginning of the function allows hotpatching.
When a function needs to be hotpatched, the mov edi,edi is replaced by a short jump instruction that jumps before the entry point of the function and the int 3 instructions are replaced by a long jump to the patched function.

Refer to [Anyone knows what "mov edi,edi " does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728170/anyone-knows-what-mov-edi-edi-does)

Don't know why __report_gsfailure is only preceeded by 2 int 3 even if it starts with a mov edi,edi instruction...

Comment: I thought about it, but turns out there're functions that start with `mov edi, edi` and at the same time there's no padding in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

[Raymond Chen tells all you need to know about this: Why do Windows functions all begin with a pointless MOV EDI, EDI instruction?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/21/10214405.aspx)

Comment: Turns out there're functions that start with mov edi, edi and at the same time there's no padding in front of them.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if you have a question related to Windows, chances are that Raymond Chen has already posted the answer, so you should be sure to check out his excellent blog, [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/), before asking.